# My script returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter "100" for "weight" and "2" for "height", I receive "0.0002" as the result and this is obviously wrong:

```js
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('#butt').click(function(){
    var hei = $("#hei").val();
    var wei = $("#wei").val();
    bmi = hei/(wei*wei);
    var result = $("#result");
    result.html("Your BMI is " + bmi);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bmi">
  <h3>Step 1: Calculating Your Body Mass Index (BMI)</h3>
  <form>
    <label>Enter Your weight (Kg)</label>
    <input type="text" name="weight" id="wei" value="">
    <br>
    <label>Enter Your height (M):</label>
    <input type="text" name="height" id="hei" value="">
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="butt">Calculate my BMI</button>
    <p id="result">Your BMI is </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is `2/(100*100) = 2/10000 = .0002` wrong?

Comment: I love how OP stated 'obviously wrong'

Comment: oh, this is not programming related; but for `bmi calculation` you should set height as `cm` not `m`.

Comment: i should buy new eyes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a maths problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: What did you expect to see as the result? if you tell us the result you wanted to see. Maybe we can explain why the current code is different than that one and how to write the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the script, but that you swapped your variables;

```
bmi = hei/(wei*wei);
```

should be

```
bmi = wei/(hei*hei);
```

Comment: It is correct but probably he has to get heights as cm too.

Comment: You're right with `wei` in *kg* and `hei` in *meters* ;)

Comment: @Arashsoft a lot of calculators ask for it in cm because people are more precise that way. The formula is Kg/M^2 though.

Comment: oh ok, so M is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Your program is correct.  Your formula is wrong.

BMI = kg/M^2

So, your formula should be:

```
bmi = wei/(hei*hei);
```

Comment: I provide the exact correct answer, and get voted down twice?  What is wrong here?

Comment: Also maybe you have to mention that height should be based on cm not m.

Comment: Not in the formula I provided.  And more to the point, his FORM requests Meters.

Comment: ok, I was wrong, M is correct for BMI.

Comment: Also, who is voting to have my post deleted?  I'm sorry I posted my answer at the exact microsecond as Bleys's.  But it's just as correct...

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you. Maybe because it doesn't add any more than the previous answer did. If you look at the timestamps yours was posted about 2.5 minutes after the previous answer. Not the same microsecond.